# How to check the version of the currently installed `pdb` (Python Debugger)?

Tags: python, pdb

To check the version of the specific python module, I heard that the following is one of the standard way:

```
python -c 'import some_module; print (__some_module__.version)'
```

But for the python debugger 'pdb', the above idea doesn't work. Then how can we check the version of the currently installed pdb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since pdb is in the standard library it uses pythons version number and does not have a version number of its own.

> In general, modules in the standard library SHOULD NOT have version numbers. They implicitly carry the version number of the Python release they are included in.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/

Comment: However csv module is also standard library, but it have it's own version with `csv.__version__` command which differs from Python version.
Urllib.request also have their own version with `urllib.request.__version__` command.

Comment: @YugoGautomo You are correct; the rest of the PEP describes these scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

`pdb` is a Python standard library. So the version of your Python is the version of your pdb (if we can talk about versions at all. You would usually say, `pdb` in Python X)

Read: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 0):

`pip freeze` will list all currently installed packages

```
pip freeze | grep pdb
```

Comment: This produced zero output for me.